# Program needs to be run as administrator in Windows 10

Tags: registry, windows-10, administrator

We have an app that ran fine in Windows 7 but needs to be run as an administrator under Windows 10.  Needless to say, this is not an optimal solution.  I know the issue is with areas of the registry that are protected when logged in as a standard user, but I can't find any documentation about which areas aren't protected, so I can move my keys there.

Comment: which keys do you write to? HKLM is always protected, write to HKCU (current user)

Answer (score 0):

Don't write/read any key in HKLM, please target only HKCU.If you need to monitor registry access and troubleshoot them, you can use tool such as [Regmon for Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/regmon.aspx).